# How to decide which value to fetch?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have jmeter script contains **five** **transactions** of which **one** **transaction** contains more than **one** **dynamic** values. And I want to know how to decide which value to fetch in order to pass it to further transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch those values which are required.

1. Record your scenario 2 times
2. Inspect request details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
3. Find request parameters (they may be in the request headers as well) which are different between 2 recordings

These are the dynamic parameters you need to correlate (extract from the previous response and pass to the next request)

---

Alternatively you can use a cloud-based JMeter scripts recording solution which is capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with **automatic correlation** of all dynamic parameters so you won't have to worry about it. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) guide for details.